# Python equivalent to `PyArrayContiguousFromAny`?

Tags: python, numpy, swig

Is there a Python equivalent to the C API's function:

```
PyArray_ContiguousFromAny(PyObject* op, int typenum, int min_depth, int max_depth)
```

`numpy.ascontiguousarray(a, dtype)` seems close, but it doesn't take a `min_depth` or `max_depth` argument giving the minimum and maximum for the dimension of the array.

If worst comes to worst, I can just call this function and then check the dimensions of the result, but that seems a bit wasteful.

Comment: The base function `np.array` takes a `ndmin` parameter, which may be equivalent of `min_depth`.  I'm not aware of an `max_depth` option when making an array from something like nested lists. `np.array` priority is to make a numeric dtype array, regardless of the required number of dimensions.

Comment: given an example (or 2) where you might to use these depth parameters.

Comment: @hpaulj: According to the documentation, "ndmin specifies the minimum number of dimension that the resulting array should have.  Ones will be prepended."  My use case is that I want exactly 1, or exactly 2 dimensions.  `ndmin` won't do that.

Comment: `np.array([1,2,3], ndmin=2)` produces a (1,3) array.  But there are other inexpensive ways of tweaking dimensions, since they all produce views - reshape, expand_dims, atleast_2d, etc.

Comment: What sort of nested sequence are you working from?  Normally I just use `np.array(aList)`, and let  numpy deduce the number and size of the dimensions from the sequence - the usual nesting of []. `np.array([[1,2,3]], float)` will make a contiguous (1,3) array with float dtype.  Other  parameters are needed only if there's something unusual about the sequence.

Comment: @hpaulj.  I'm writing a user interface to a C library.  Say that the library requires its input to be a 1-dimensional array, and that the library gets the length and data.  `PyArray_ContiguousFromArray` conveniently lets me take whatever the user gives me, whether it be [1, 2, 3], (1, 2, 3), np.array((1, 2, 3)) and guarantees me a 1-dimensional array, and a None on anything that can't be made into a 1-dimensional array.  I'm trying to move as much code as I can out of SWIG and into Python, which is easier to write and to debug.

Comment: @hpaulj. Also.  Imagine I need to create several output arrays based on the size of an input array.  (C code tends to use out variables).  Given a particular user input, I'd like to know (in Python) what `PyArray_ContiguousFromArray` is going to turn it into, so I can know precisely the length of the arrays I need to build for output arguments.

Comment: If you need to ensure the result is 1d, `ravel` is a cheap tool to do that.

Comment: @hpaulj: If the user passes me a 2-dimensional array and I want a 1-dimensional array, this is an error. I repeat:  I want to verify *in Python* that the user's input satisfies the requirements of the C API.  I can do that using PyArray_*.  I was hoping there was an easy way to do it in Python.  I'm not looking for ways to coerce an input to a specific dimension.

Comment: it's trivial to check an array's `ndim`, `shape` and `dtype`.  I can't picture the circumstances where the c-api would give different results.  I haven't used the c-api, but am  quite familiar with the regular numpy usage.